# How to give rectangle shape styling css to selected tab as shown in the below screenshot?

Tags: css, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

[image]

I want to make my tab like this but not getting how to do it.

I tried the below code also for sample shape but it didn't come.

```
#demo:before {
        border-width: 10px;
        border-top-color: #ccc;
        border-left-width: 50px;
        border-right-width: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

#demo:after {
        border-width: 2px;
        border-top-color: #777;
        border-left-width: 50px;
        border-right-width: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please share the html markup too please

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding an after pseudo element on the a element.

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#">Notifications</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
</ul>

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
}

ul li + li {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: helvetica;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li a.active:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 16px;
  right: 16px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qnwe098m/7/

Comment: Hi AggelosB. Thanks for your reply. The code which you sent is working if i'm using bootstrap tabs but if i'm using angular-ui tabs i cannot apply this code. Here is the code for angular-ui tabs:                                                                    <div class="row"><uib-tabset justified="true">
       <uib-tab heading="Device Management"><div class="container-fluid" id="googleMap" ></div></uib-tab>
       <uib-tab heading="User Management"></uib-tab>
       <uib-tab heading="Notifications">

Comment: you can find the tabs code in angular-ui tabs code in the following link:           https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/     Waiting for your help.